# Manga where an orange haired boy ends up working and living with a group of super heroes

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a colored webcomic not sure if it was in webtoon.

The main character is an orange haired boy who, under some circumstances, ends up working and living with a group of super heroes.

I think there was a scene where he was wearing a wig and they thought he was a girl... I think his sister forced him to wear it and go get something from the vending machine.

That's vaguely all I remember, it's been a long time

Answer (score 3):

Found it! It was Chaos Attack.

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/ChaosAttack) (warning)

> Chaos Attack takes place in a world where violent aliens hiding amongst humans is a growing phenomenon. To combat this threat, many teams of superheroes employed by the International Heroes Association (IHA) fight them, but often grow to become celebrities. The IHA then decides to form their own new team of superheroes, composed of five young men, each with a unique and useful superpower.
>
> Sadly, they're selfish, lazy, insist on having days off, and will only rescue pretty girls.
>
> Enter Doah Lee, a young boy who lost his parents when he was very young, and only wants to be able to live a normal life. Sadly, his three older sisters often get in the way of this. When we're introduced to him, they'd already forced Doah to dress up as a girl and get them sodas.
>
> With Doah making a surprisingly attractive girl, he is both attacked by an alien and soon rescued by the Chaos Men, and who instantly take a liking to Doah. When Doah reveals his gender to them, the Chaos Men become outraged, and eventually insist that in order to pay them back, Doah must act as their manager—so they can get their paychecks from the IHA and have him cook and clean for them.